# Navbar ul with distance on left

Tags: html, css, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, navbar

I want to make my navigation bar with dropdown, but there is always distance on left side of the div dropdown. How do I remove that distance?

Here is the code of the navigation bar:

```
.navbar {
                background-color: #6b6b6b;
                margin:10px;
            }
            .navbar ul {
                display: inline;
                color: white;
                font-family: "Agency FB";
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                list-style-type: none;
                font-size: 24px;
            }

            .navbar ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                padding-right: 10px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-top: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
            }

            .navbar ul li:hover {
                background-color: #cccccc;
            }
            .navbar ul li ul {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left:-10px;
                margin-top:5px;
                background-color:white;
                color:#6b6b6b;
                padding-left:-20px;
                font-size:20px;
            }

            .navbar ul li ul li { 
              display: block; 
            }

            .navbar ul li:hover ul {
                display: block;
                opacity: 1;
                visibility: visible;
            }
```

And here is the code of html navigation bar (without link):

```
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Home
            </li>
            <li>
                Category
                <ul>
                    <li>Batik</li>
                    <li>Party</li>
                    <li>Office</li>
                    <li>Casual</li>
                    <li>Sport</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Information
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        About Us
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Cara Belanja
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Our Location
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Contact Us
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

I remade it for you kinda, I'm sure you'll get the jist of it

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Category</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Information</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/un64F/3/ for css

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for exactly but does adding `padding-left: 0;` to the `.navbar ul` style have the effect you want?